# Gauss Elimination Method with partial pivoting

Tags: algorithms

We got following system of equation :

$0.61X+1.23Y+1.72Z=0.792$

$1.02X+2.15Y-5.51Z=12.0$

$-4.34X+11.2Y-4.25Z=16.3$

with partial pivoting solution set is $\left \{1.59,1.6,-1.25  \right \}$. If the same problem is solved without pivoting the solution set is $\left \{0.79,2.00,-1.25  \right \}$.

When we plugin $\left \{1.59,1.6,-1.25  \right \}$ in first equation we get $0.7363$ on LHS which is not equal to $0.792$
But when we plugin $\left \{0.79,2.00,-1.25  \right \}$ in first equation we get $0.7919$ or $ 0.792$ on LHS which is equal to $0.792 $ on RHS.

Why is the solution set $\left \{0.79,2.00,-1.25  \right \}$ without pivoting unacceptable ? 
In my book the reason is that 0.79 is not even correct to one significant figure.

Comment: You said when you plug in the pivoting solution {1.59,1.6,-1.28} you didn't get the right answer, but when you plug in the one with pivoting you got the right answer. Did you state the wrong way?

Comment: both sides are not equal for pivoting solution but equal for solution without pivoting.

Answer (score 0):

If you plug in the pivoting solution, you get

$$ 0.7879\\
  11.9493\\
  16.3319$$

which is close enough to the right hand side.

If you plug in the non-pivoting solution, you get

$$
   0.7919\\
  11.9933\\
  24.2839$$

You can see the 3rd one is very far from the original.